# Does _FILE_OFFSET_SIZE work after prior inclusion of stdio.h?

Tags: c, posix

I want to use `fseeko`, and so have this:

```
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
#include <stdio.h>
```

Because source is intended for all sorts of platforms and architectures there are many surrounding preprocessor switches for each, making it unpreferable to copy into source files where used. However, if putting this in a header I fear this would require that header to be included first, which may be difficult to enforce.

Testing whether an stdio.h macro is defined or not might work, e.g. `SEEK_CUR`, but that is ugly in its own ways since there is no standard, self-explainatory `STDIO_INCLUDED`-macro to test for.

Some headers allow multiple inclusion with different switches, like `assert.h` and `NDEBUG`. I was wondering if this is also the case according to POSIX standard for `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` and other similar switches.

Comment: Most, if not all, macro switches are documented in [future_test_macros](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. Why does my reading skills get a boost right after asking a question in public. From `fseeko` page, emphasis mine:

> On some architectures, both off_t and long are 32-bit types, but defining _FILE_OFFSET_BITS with the value 64 ***(before including any header files)*** will turn off_t into a 64-bit type.

The answer is no.